# pattern matching with sub(), unable to catch and replace first occurrence

Tags: r, regex

The followings are the results I expect

```
> title = "La La Land (2016/I)"
[1]"(2016" #result
> title = "_The African Americans: Many Rivers to Cross with Henry Louis Gates, Jr._ (2013) _The Black Atlantic (1500-1800) (#1.1)_"
[1]"(2013" #result
> title = "dfajfj(2015)asdfjuwer f(2017)fa.erewr6"
[1]"(2015" #result
```

==================================================================

The followings are what I got by applying code`sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}.*\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")`

```
> title = "_The African Americans: Many Rivers to Cross with Henry Louis Gates, Jr._ (2013) _The Black Atlantic (1500-1800) (#1.1)_"
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}.*\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1] "(1500-1800) (#1.1)"  #result. However, I expected it to be "(2013)"
> title = "La La Land (2016/I)"
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}.*\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1] "(2016/I)" #result as I expect
> title = "dfajfj(2015)asdfjuwer f(2017)fa.erewr6"
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}.*\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1]"(2017)" # result. However, I expect it to be "（2015)"
```

The followings are what I GOT by applying code`sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")`

```
> title = "La La Land (2016/I)"
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1] "La La Land (2016/I)" #result. However, I expect it to be "(2016)"
> title = "dfajfj(2015)asdfjuwer f(2017)fa.erewr6" 
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1] "(2017)" #result. However, I expect it to be "(2015)"
> title = "_The African Americans: Many Rivers to Cross with Henry Louis Gates, Jr._ (2013) _The Black Atlantic (1500-1800) (#1.1)_"
> sub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
[1] "(2013)" #result as I expect
```

I checked the description of `sub`, it says "sub performs replacement of the first match. In this case, the first match should be `(2013)`.

In a word, I try to write a `sub()`command to return the first occurrence of a year in a string.

I guess there is something wrong with my code but couldn't find it, appreciate if anyone could help me.

==================================================================

In fact, my ultimate goal is to extract the year of all movies. However, I don't know how to do it in one step. Therefore, I decide to first find the year in `(dddd` format, then use code `sub(pattern="\\((\\d{4}).*", a, replacement="\\1")` to find the pure number of the year.

for example:

```
> a= "(2015"
> sub(pattern="\\((\\d{4}).*", a, replacement="\\1")
[1] "2015"
> a= "(2015)"
> sub(pattern="\\((\\d{4}).*", a, replacement="\\1")
[1] "2015"
```

=================**updated 05/29/2017 22:51PM**=======================

the `str_extract` in akrun's answer works well with my dataset.

However, the `sub()` doesn't work for all data. The following are what I did. However, my code doesn't work with all 500 records. I would really appreciate if anyone could point out the mistakes on my codes. I really cannot figure it out myself. Thank you very much.

```
> t1
[1] "Man Who Fell to Earth (Remix) (2010) (TV)"
> t2
[1] "Manual pr\u0087ctico del amigo imaginario (abreviado) (2008)"
> title = c(t1,t2)
> x=gsub(pattern=".*(\\(\\d{4}.*\\)).*", title, replacement="\\1")
> x
[1] "(2010) (TV)" "(2008)"     
> sub(pattern="\\((.*)\\).*", x, replacement="\\1")
[1] "2010) (TV" "2008"
```

However, my goal is to get `2010` and `2008`. My code works with `t2` but fails with `t1`

Comment: Using your new update, `title2 <- c( "Man Who Fell to Earth (Remix) (2010) (TV)", "Manual pr\u0087ctico del amigo imaginario (abreviado) (2008)");
 sub(".*\\(([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", title2)
#[1] "2010" "2008"`

Comment: thank you very much, @arkun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match 0 or more characters that are not a `(`  (`[^(]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by a `(` and four digits (`\\([0-9]{4}`) which we capture as a group (`(...)`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^[^(]*(\\([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", title)
#[1] "(2016" "(2013" "(2015"
```

If we need to remove the `(`, then capture only the numbers that follows the `\\(` as a group

```
sub("^[^(]*\\(([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", title)
#[1] "2016" "2013" "2015"
```

---

Or with `str_extract`, we use a regex lookaround to extract the 4 digit numbers that follows the `(`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(title, "(?<=\\()[0-9]{4}")
#[1] "2016" "2013" "2015"
```

---

Or with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(title, regexpr("(?<=\\()([0-9]{4})", title, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "2016" "2013" "2015"
```

#### data

```
title <- c("La La Land (2016/I)", 
 "_The African Americans: Many Rivers to Cross with Henry Louis Gates, Jr._ (2013) _The Black Atlantic (1500-1800) (#1.1)_", 
"dfajfj(2015)asdfjuwer f(2017)fa.erewr6")
```

Comment: by the way, I would really appreciate if you could take a look at my codes and point outt my mistakes. that would help me a lot in using ```sub()``` . your code works great with most data records on my datasets. However, it does not work with 500 records. I already updated the question with some of the 500 records and my code. However, my code doesn't work with all the 500 records. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code on my own. Thank you again for your help.